# CSS assigning fonts to font weights

Tags: css, fonts

Is it possible to assign different fonts to different font-weights?

For example, If I have 2 fonts, "helvetica roman" and "helvetica bold" and I want a font-weight of 500 to always display "helvetica roman" and a font-weight of 700 to always display "helvetica bold"

I know this functionality is available through cufon, but would like to use it with straight CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an attribute selector. Maybe it's possible to achieve it... I don't know how though. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: tying one presentational attribute to another seems unnecessarily complex.  Your HTML should include enough meta-information (classes, ids, meaningful structure) that you can target something other than the font-weight (font-weight itself shouldn't be included in the HTML, rather it should be abstracted behind classes, ids, or header-levels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `font-weight` style inline, then you can use ([example on jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ru5t9/))

```
*[style~="font-weight:"][style~="500;"]
{
    /* Font 1 */
}
*[style~="font-weight:"][style~="700;"]
{
    /* Font 2 */
}
```

I'm not sure about browser compatibility (the above was tested on Firefox). And I recommend using `classes` instead. Also, this probably isn't bullet proof.

Comment: You've got me conflicted.  On one hand, that's a very clever solution--on the other hand the *only* time I feel like this should include a disclaimer about how abnormal it is, and how it's smells like the wrong solution to the task at hand.

Comment: ...but +1 for answering the question

Comment: This is as close as one can get using CSS I think. I don't think I'll actually be using this solution (ever) :) , but good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting things backwards, but not far off the mark.  Use the various header-levels (h1, h2, etc) and assign CSS to those!  They already imply weights, and each can be assigned a distinct font via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really how CSS works. You want to use classes or tags instead, preferably with semantic meaning. You don't assign styles based on stylistic information (like font weight); you assign them based on semantic information (like "does this have class `Header`?" or "is this marked as `strong`?")

```
.Header /* or h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, or strong, or any combination of these */
{
    font-family: "Helvetica Bold";
}

.Normal /* or just body, and everything will inherit it unless overriden */
{
    font-family: "Helvetica Roman";
}
```